# Loading javascript or css files from external URL giving Warning insecure content

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps, google-gadget, gmail-contextual-gadgets

i am developing a gmail contextual gadget in this gadget there are some images.can any one please tell how to load images in contextual gadget.for example i am hosting my Method spec at  http://cloudfactor9.appspot.com/first_app3.xml and there are http://cloudfactor9.appspot.com/assets/img/cflogo.png when in first_app3.xml i declare a

```
<img src="assets/img/man.png" class="man-image"><img>
```

it gives me 404 not found error.

when i declare img element in this way .its giving me warning

```
<img src="http://cloudfactor9.appspot.com/assets/img/man.png" class="man-image"><img>


Warning: The page at https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&shva=1#inbox/140d95d0cccc60a5 displayed insecure content from http://cloudfactor9.appspot.com/assets/img/cflogo.png.
```

i want to get rid of this warning. what is the proper way of loading images ,javascript and stylesheets in google contextual gadget please guideline.

Comment: Note gmail is using https and your image URL has http

Answer (score 1):

You have the "insecure content" problem described [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1342714?hl=en) (for Google Chrome, but it is the same for all major browsers). You should configure your application "cloudfactor9" to force secure connections on some (or all) of the URLs, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Secure_URLs):

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>profile</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/profile/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Then you can access your resources via HTTPS (**https**://cloudfactor9.appspot.com/assets/img/cflogo.png) from a page that is retrieved via HTTPS (like those at mail.google.com).

Comment: @ritesh-mehandiratta, if (and only if) my answer helped you, feel free to accept it clicking on the check mark symbol on the left :)

Answer (score 0):

Your static content is served off of an insecure protocol (http) hence the warning. The proper approach would be to just include your static content be included with just the "protocol relative" URL. For example, you would do;